# Grub 1.98 on Ubuntu 10.04 ignores grub.cfg, goes for menu.lst instead

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, grub

I've got a VPS that's merrily running Ubuntu 10.04 server (I believe it's on Xen). I was doing some kernel maintenance and updating grub when I noticed that the `update-grub` tool writes an accurate `grub.cfg`, but this is apparently ignored by Grub in favour of `menu.lst`, which the update tool ignores.

Sure enough, if I manually edit `menu.lst`, I can boot into whatever kernel I like.

Why this discrepancy? Is this a quirk of the VM template that my hosting provider uses, or is something else broken?

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -S /usr/sbin/update-grub`? and then `apt-cache show {package}` where {package} is the name dpkg returns?

Comment: `grub-pc: /usr/sbin/update-grub` is the output of `dpkg`, and I've got a pastebin for the `apt-cache show` output: http://pastebin.com/XRZUPdeH

Comment: Was the system updated from a previous version?  Are you sure that the grub binary in the bootloader got upgraded as well?  Can you try doing a ` dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc`, and make sure it updates your MBR?

Answer (score 1):

Grub2 uses grub.cfg, not Grub1.

Comment: Just to be clear: Grub 1.98 is Grub 2

Comment: That is obviously correct, but does it really answer the question?.  The question seems to have more to do with the tools on Debian/Ubuntu to automatically write a configuration.

Comment: This is the point - `update-grub` seems to create `grub.cfg`, but the grub bootloader seems to read `menu.lst` on boot. Surely this isn't broken by default on Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: Yeah, I answered you yesterday in comments @growse but it looks like SO ate my post. I'm tempted to think your idea about the VM template is right at the moment, this doesn't seem like Ubuntu behavior.